# How to create a web form to create a button and it's embedded code?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing an academic project, I need to create a button (as like/share button of facebook)who's height, width, text, link, and color are entered through form. The form has to generate button and its embedded code and preview on the same form.I am using bootstrap 3.0.

Comment: You seem to have written a requirements specification for a complete piece of software. That's not really the right scope for a Stackoverflow question. You might be better off hiring a freelance developer than asking here.

Comment: Is there any tutorial links available?
I do not mean a fully developed code. @Quentin

Comment: maybe you could use some html input, then set the values as variables and using javascript you pre-create a standard basic code replacing some style with the variables you set and then display the full code inside a text area...
Just a possible approach of thisù

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getcode()
    {
        var code='<button style="height:'+document.getElementById('height').value + 'px; width:'+document.getElementById('width').value + 'px; background-color:'+document.getElementById('color').value + '"></button>';
        document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML=code;
        document.getElementById('code').value=code;
    }
</script>

    <input type="text" id="width" />
    <input type="text" id="height" />
    <input type="color" id="color" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="getcode()" />

<textarea id="code"></textarea>

<div id="preview"></div>
```